# Не работает JQuery slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, toggle

SlideToggle отказывается работать на странице сайта, хотя на специально созданной тестовой страничке с точно таким же html-кодом и JQuery все работает прекрасно (Параграф открывается и закрывается при нажатии на кнопку).

Скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.house-full-description').hide();
$('.read-more-btn').click(function() {
    $('.house-full-description').slideToggle(400);
  }); });
```

HTML-код:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 class="house-type">Дома из бруса</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
    <p class="house-full-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button class="read-more-btn">Читать далее</button>
</div>
```

В JQuery новичок, почти 3 часа искал ответ - как видите, ничего не нашел.

P.S. Скрипт и библиотеку JQuery я, естественно, подключил. Самое забавное, что hide() на параграф работает, и даже show() вместо slideToggle(), однако мне нужно иметь возможность развернуть и свернуть параграф текста / блок обратно.

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- My scripts -->
<script src="js/slideToggle.js"></script>
```

Скрипт добавлял и просто в теги , не только в отдельный файл - тщетно.

Вот что пишет консоль Mozilla:

https://i.gyazo.com/a29e60b342ad69737494610ca445962a.png

Comment: Трудно определить, почему не работает у вас, пока не будет примера, воспроизводящего проблему.

Comment: если используете bootstrap - по default из коробки уже есть данная реализация - accordion https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя 4 часа разобрался - Скрипты Bootstrap'a каким-то образом перезаписывали скрипты JQuery. Решил проблему, разместив последние под скриптами Bootstrap'a, прямо перед `</body>`. Наконец-то все работает! :)

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Читать далее</button>
  
</div>
```